# Why does `\raggedleft` not work?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

I want to position the author of the quote on the right hand side of the quote.

Why does `\raggedleft` not work?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{textquote}{ O{}+b}
    {\begin{samepage}\begin{addmargin}{2.5cm}\guillemotright#2\guillemotleft\end{addmargin}\end{samepage}}
    {\footnotesize \raggedleft \textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{textquote}[René Descartes]
        [...] I think therefore I am.
    \end{textquote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you test your environment with `\end{textquote}test` you will see that the name gets typeset in the same paragraph as the text after your environment. Once this paragraph ends, you are no longer in `\raggedleft` mode.

To avoid this, you should finish the paragraph at the end of your environment:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{textquote}{ O{}+b}
    {\begin{samepage}\begin{addmargin}{2.5cm}\guillemotright#2\guillemotleft\end{addmargin}\end{samepage}}
    {\footnotesize \raggedleft \textbf{#1}\par}

\begin{document}
    \begin{textquote}[René Descartes]
        [...] I think therefore I am.
    \end{textquote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is that? Does LaTeX wait for the paragraph to be finished until aligning it?

Comment: If you switch back and forth between alignments within the same paragraph, it uses the one which is in effect when the paragraph finishes.

Comment: Makes sense. Good to know. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @mrCarnivore You might also want to make the adding the name etc. conditional if it is empty or not. This would avoid extra space in case of a quote without author.

Comment: Very good point! I will.

Comment: Can you also tell me, why adding the margin distance does not work when changing to `\NewDocumentEnvironment{parquote}{O{2.5cm}+b}
 {\begin{samepage}\begin{addmargin}{#1}`?

Comment: @mrCarnivore If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but there are several errors in your code.

1. The argument to `textquote` is mandatory, not optional.
2. There is no vertical space around the quote.
3. There is a feasible page break point between the quote and the attribution.
4. You miss a `\par` at the end so that `\raggedleft` can do its work (but `\raggedleft` is not the right tool).

Fixed code.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}% not Helvetica, please
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{textquote}{m +b}{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{samepage}\begin{addmargin}{2.5cm}
  \guillemotright#2\guillemotleft
  \end{addmargin}\par\nopagebreak
  {\footnotesize\hspace*{\fill}\textbf{#1}\par}
  \end{samepage}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{textquote}{René Descartes}
[\dots] I think therefore I am.
\end{textquote}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{textquote}{Somebody Else}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{textquote}

\lipsum[4][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The image below shows why you shouldn't use Helvetica for longer texts. Other sans serif fonts can (and should) be used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. 1-3 I had already addressed after the first answer. What is better with 4 than `\raggedleft`? Also, I did not get what you wanted to show me as bad for the `Helvetica`part.

Comment: Adding the vspaces before and after do lead to problems when using `[parskip=full]` option of `scrlttr2`... How to prevent that?

Comment: What do you think about `\vspace{-\parskip}\bigskip` instead of `\addvspace{\topsep}`. This leads to always exactly one line of distance.

Comment: @mrCarnivore I think this is the worst possibility. If you plan to use a nonzero `\parskip` (which I deem horrible, but it's personal opinion), just don't add spaces.

Comment: Of course I want to use `\parskip`. However, with your solution there is quite a lot of whitespace between the last paragraph and the quote... Also, what and why do you have against Helvetica?